# See reviews in all languages - all regions in windows store

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-store, localization

When I open Store app in Windows 8.1, I see very little reviews for application, because the app is only showing reviews in Czech. Is it possible to set it up to show all reviews? I am using English as my UI language, but I have Czech Republic as my "Country or region".

Comment: The simplest solution would be to change your region.  You do this by Changing your location from the `control panel / region / change location`

Comment: Not exactly what I would like, but it is probably the best solution available..

Comment: This is an issue that bugs me the most. I'm from a small country, and many apps don't have any reviews.